# machine learning for product categorization, how many document per category?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I'm going to use deepdetect (http://www.deepdetect.com) for product categorization.
And I was wondering if there are some general numbers to work with to get an accurate classification.
Like how many products per category, total of products, etc...
I'm also interested in text vs image classification. Is one more accurate than the other or just depends on how much data you feed during the learning phase?

Thanks,
Isaac

Comment: The short answer is "no". It all depends on particular problem, and in general - more is better, there is nothing more to say without particular dataset.

Comment: thanks, that's what I thought, I guess it's going to be a matter of get as many products per category as possible and then start.

Comment: Perhaps this [short list](http://developers.thequestionmark.org/2017/01/31/product-categorization-with-machine-learning#prior-work) is helpful for a rough idea of what might be possible (text-based).

Comment: Awesome @wvengen, it's really close to what we want to do :-D